# C Math equation assigns a variable correctly only once

Tags: c, gtk, equation

Im having problems assigning the variable `global_duty`.  All the other variables in the equation are assigned every time.  As far as I can tell the text label `duty_out_lab` is reset at least twice.  Ive tried declaring `global_duty` as `int` , `gint` and `gdouble,` but nothing seems to work.  The first time the equation is used it gives the right answer, then every other time it outputs just 0.  Everything compiles without any warnings.

Here is  the relevant code.

```
#include <gtk/gtk.h>    
int global_ontime;
int global_offtime;
int global_duty;
GtkWidget *duty_out_lab;

static void 
set_duty ()
{
   global_duty = global_ontime / (global_ontime + global_offtime) * 100 ;  
   gchar *str = g_strdup_printf (" %d  percent ", global_duty);
   gtk_label_set_text (GTK_LABEL (duty_out_lab), str);
   g_free(str);
   printf ("On time is %d micro seconds\n", global_ontime);
   printf ("Off time is %d micro seconds\n", global_offtime);  
   printf ("Duty cycle is %d percent \n\n", global_duty);   
}

static void
set_ontime (GtkSpinButton *spinbutton, gpointer user_data)
{
   gint value1 = gtk_spin_button_get_value_as_int (spinbutton);
   global_ontime = value1;
   set_duty();
}

static void
set_offtime (GtkSpinButton *spinbutton, gpointer user_data)
{
   gint value2 = gtk_spin_button_get_value_as_int (spinbutton);
   global_offtime = value2;
   set_duty();
}
```

Output from terminal

```
On time is 1 micro seconds
Off time is 0 micro seconds
Duty cycle is 100 percent 

On time is 1 micro seconds
Off time is 1 micro seconds
Duty cycle is 0 percent 

On time is 1 micro seconds
Off time is 2 micro seconds
Duty cycle is 0 percent 

On time is 2 micro seconds
Off time is 2 micro seconds
Duty cycle is 0 percent
```

gtk outputs

][2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lfPH3.png) output good

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FEe84.png) output bad

Comment: Please post your observations, not your conclusions. If your program produces output, don't describe it in free prose, copy and paste it verbatim.

Comment: On time is 1 micro seconds
Off time is 0 micro seconds
Duty cycle is 100 percent 

On time is 1 micro seconds
Off time is 1 micro seconds
Duty cycle is 0 percent 

On time is 1 micro seconds
Off time is 2 micro seconds
Duty cycle is 0 percent 

On time is 2 micro seconds
Off time is 2 micro seconds
Duty cycle is 0 percent

Comment: when I pasted it in the format changed

Comment: Please [edit] your question. Coments are not suitable for posting updates.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First step: Declare the variable global_duty as float or double.

Second step: Replace the line

```
global_duty = global_ontime / (global_ontime + global_offtime) * 100 ;
```

by

```
global_duty = global_ontime * 1.0 / (global_ontime + global_offtime) * 100 ;
```

In C, the result of 2 (an int) divided by 5 (an int) is 0 (an int) and not 0.4 (a float/double). Similarly, in your case, the value of global_duty was getting truncated to 0. If you want decimal values as answer, use 'float' or 'double' data types. Multiplying the numerator by 1.0 makes the data type of numerator as double.

Comment: @fenny500: accept the answer, if it solves your issue

Comment: It worked     Just curious is there a way to format it to less decimal places?

Comment: To print answer upto 3 decimal places use %.3f   in place of %f for float values and so on.  On a side note, click on the tick mark icon to the left of answer to accept it. You havent accepted it yet.

Comment: "Multiplying the numerator by 1.0 makes the data type of numerator as float." should be " ... as `double`".

Comment: @chux: fixed it

Comment: @ Ashish kulkarni    Thanks for your reply, Tve clicked  on it twice now, I think I saw it say something to the effect of that I didnt have enough posts to my name to cast a vote but it thanked me for my input. Anyhow it was a good cal and saved me alot of time.  I will click on it again,

Comment: @ Ashish kulkarni  my mistake, I clicked the arrow not the tick, so thats fixed

Comment: @chux:  Thanks for the input,  It was lucky for me , I chose double ar rhe time.

Comment: Worst way I've seen for casting a variable. If you want a double just cast it to a double, e.g. `duty = (double) on / (off+on) * 100` or `duty = on / (off+on) * 100.`.